# How to upload to MINIO using multipart/formdata POST request in python with a presigned url

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, minio

I have a presigned url policy. But when I try to upload to it using:

```
data = {
    'policy': '<policy_str>',
    'x-amz-algorithm': '<algo>',
    'x-amz-credential': '<cred>',
    'x-amz-date': '20230111T110342Z',
    'x-amz-signature': '<sign>',
    'bucket': 'temp',
    'key': 'object.txt',  
}

files = {
    'json': (None, json.dumps(data), 'application/json'),
    'file': ('a.txt', open('a.txt', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
}

r = requests.post('https://<minio_url>/temp/', data=data, verify=False)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

But I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code><Message>Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the Credential is mal-formed; expecting &#34;&lt;YOUR-AKID&gt;/YYYYMMDD/REGION/SERVICE/aws4_request&#34;.</Message><BucketName>temp</BucketName><Resource>/temp/</Resource><RequestId>773531234560CB56</RequestId><HostId>6ea96d23-c563-77a1-4038-d995deda5437</HostId></Error>
```

I have tried the above approach. But I'm getting the malformed credentials error. I need to use the POST request itself as I want to be able to control the max content size.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just include the XML content of the error in your question as text, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: I have done this. Please help me with this in case you know about it